# Make a function to sum the elements of a list and return a string

Tags: python, string, sum

I need to make a function to sum the elements of a list and return a string
Also if the list is empty it should return the string "0=0"

So far I have

```
n=[1,5,7]
o=[]
def sum_eq(n):
    answer=sum(n)
    return print(str(n), "=", str(answer))

    if not n:
        return print (str("0=0"))

sum_eq(n)
```

I know my results according to the code will return

```
[1,5,7]=13
```

but I have tried to use % or format but it gives me coding errors

I am looking to obtain a string like this

```
1 + 5 + 7 = 13
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I get a message telling me the format is not correct (invalid syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sum_eq(n):
    print(' + '.join([str(i) for i in n]),'=',sum(n))
```